# How do you find the value of a physical product over a period of time?

Tags: price, selling

Let's say you have a limited edition Ibanez rg1570 guitar and you wanted to find out what the average selling price was each year?

I'd like to get a clue as to whether I should sell my asset now, Or hold on for a few months while the value rises.

If the answer depends on the product,  are there any general methods that I can use to get the price for each past year?

Comment: If you know what the sale price of the item each year, why not just take the average? If you only know what the item would sell for *now*, or at one specific point in the past, you don't have enough data to compute meaningful statistics.

Comment: I haven't been keeping track of it year on year or I'd do that.  But If I wanted to buy something used with the intent to sell again in a few years.  Perhaps I should reword to point out I'd like to find the trend of items in the past as well as the future?

Comment: Value isn't simply something you assign to an item.  Value is a concept of how beneficial/valuable a group of people think something is.  People's mentality fluctuates w/ numerous variables, including their preferences, usage, and group mentality/market/peer pressure.  Knowing that, what you are asking is not a straightforward answer, by any means.  Who is your target market/audience (rhetorical)?  Craigslist, eBay, pawn shop, guitar store, etc?  How does your target audience(s) value fluctuate?  How can you find a history of that fluctuation?  Google searches? Word-of-mouth?  Do this research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One strategy, more forward-looking, is to set up a saved search with an online marketplace like [eBay](http://www.ebay.com).

With a saved search, eBay would email you when an item matching your search gets listed.  You can add the items to your personal watch list and monitor closing prices or failed listing prices.

Often, it's buyers that use the feature to locate newly-listed items they're interested in bidding on.  Yet, using a saved search is also a valid strategy for a potential seller looking to find out *(a)* the likely value for an item you may want to sell, as well as *(b)* what kinds of listings work best (e.g. free shipping, or not? auction, or set price? How should the item be described, if you do choose to list yours? etc.)

Over time, assuming the item you're interested in selling has an adequate market, you should accumulate sufficient information on the price for similar items to inform your decision to keep or sell.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably have to find a website dedicated to collecting items of that type. Before the internet there were books dedicated to yearly prices for stamps, coins, comic books and baseball cards. Now this information is sold via subscription to a website or web service.

Some of these services will let you research one or two items for free, but most will charge by the month or year.

Comment: Are you allowed to name one of these sites, or what search term on google might find then :D